# Frequency of characters in text

Tags: text, frequency, alphabet

A method to return the frequencies of repeated characters

- The answer is always the number of all characters in text, not repeated characters! Can I know how to edit it?

  ```
  public static int freq(String in ) {

    int frequency = 0;
    char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {

      for (int i = 0; i < in .length(); i++) {
        if (alphabet[j] == in .charAt(i)) {
          ++frequency;
        }
      }
    }

    return frequency;

  }
  ```

Comment: You should give an example input, and the obtained and expected result.

Comment: @SergeBallesta if input from user is: Hello, then the output is 5 instead of 2 (Repeated "L")

Comment: And what should be the output for `Hello you so old`? 2 for the `ll`, 3 for 3 total `l` or 4 for 4 total `o` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta it should give all repeated characters

Comment: *all repeated characters* is not an int value ;-). What value would you expect and why?